# Laravel Webpack Compilation

Tags: laravel, webpack

I am trying to use my simple function in `resources/assets/js/app.js`
which is :

```
require('./partial/bootstrap');
require('./partial/bootstrap-notify');

function notifme(icon,text){
      $.notify({
       // options
       icon: 'icon',        
       message: 'text'       
     })
}
```

I want to call it in my template by:

```
@section('footer-scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
           notifme('fa fa-user-circle','Logged In');
         });        
     </script>
@endsection
```

But after compiling my app.js with webpack, my functions not accessible because webpack add extra to my app.js file( i just copy the section of the compiled function because it's long):

```
   /* 9 */
  /***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

  __webpack_require__(10);
  __webpack_require__(35);

    function notifme(icon, text) {
        $.notify({
            // options
            icon: 'icon',
            message: 'text'
        });
}

/***/ }),
```

It's only working if I add my function on a separate file with no compilation.

Is there any way that I can put my function inside my main app.js file ?

Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: notifme is not defined
>       at HTMLDocument. ((index):61)
>       at mightThrow (app.js:4062)
>       at process (app.js:4130)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your definition to:

```
window.notifme = function () {
    ...
}
```

**Edit**

so your `resources/assets/js/app.js` file should look like:

```
require('./partial/bootstrap');
require('./partial/bootstrap-notify');

window.notifme = function (icon, text) {
    $.notify({
        // options
        icon: 'icon',
        message: 'text'
    })
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @behzad Can you give a little more information e.g. are you getting an error or is it just not working the way you want it to?

Comment: Are you definitely calling the function after you've included the script? Have you definitely recompiled the .js file? Have you've done a hard refresh or the page to clear your browser cache? The webpack gubbins shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: yes. i have done all that. the only way that is working is to put my function on a seprate file...to not compiled but webpack..

Comment: Was the error you got from your browser console or from your command line? Also, are you calling the function from your html or from another file that get's included in your `app.js`?

Comment: In that case would you edit your question and add your entire `esources/assets/js/app.js`? Also, was the error you got from your browser console or from your command line?

Comment: tnx Ross Thanks for your concern... i update my questions.

Comment: @behzad You haven't updated `resources/assets/js/app.js` to include the code from my answer?! I've updated my answer to include what your file should look like.